# Search by Mutual Friends Count - Friend System Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am creating a Friend System in my Forum.

I am having a tough time trying to figure out how I would grab users and order by the mutual_friend count.

I am trying to build a page that shows a list of recommended friends.

Here is my structure of tables:

```
users table
-----
user_id | name |

friends table
-----
friend_id | from_id | to_id
```

Here is an example of what is happening.

Suppose there are total of `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`,`E`,`F` =  6 people in the site.

- I am `A`,  and `B`,`C` are my friends.
- `D` and `E` in turn are friends of `B`.
- `D` is also a friend of `C` but `E` is ***not*** a friend of `C`.
- `F` is not a friend of anyone in the site.

Therefore from above data it looks like `D` and `E` are mutual friends of me (`A`). `F` is ***not*** a mutual friend of mine.

Since `D` is a friend of both `B` and `C` and `E` is friend of ***only*** `B`:

- `A` and `D` has `2` mutual friends.
- `A` and `E` has `1` mutual friend.
- `A` and `F` has `0` mutual friend.

Now if I want to search (remember i am `A`) for people who are not my friends I can do something like:

`$myfriends = "2,3"; //putting all my friends in a variable`

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN( $myfriends )`

But it will yield in terms of `user_id ASC` .

How can I make it search in `DESC` order of `mutual_friends`. ?

I am `A` i.e `user_id = 1`

i.e. *Person with more mutual friends comes first*

Please can anyone show me how can I do this? I have been stuck here for a long while. I searched for lots of thing but can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you please include the code you've tried? As it stands it's a bit difficult to figure out where your problem is.

Comment: @Phrancis the problem is how can i order `DESC` the `select` by `no_of_mutual_friends` .

Comment: Oh. Let me write something up then

Comment: Just have to say this here DO NOT USE RESERVED WORD FOR COLUMN NAMES. FROM is a reserved word so change that column to anything else. I am going to change it in my answer below,

Comment: @Phrancis You havent written anything dude!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query will take the reciprocity of relationships into account, so it doesn't matter if the relationship goes "From A to B" or "From B to A", it will still return the expected result.  So given tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE people
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO people
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (2, 'B'),
    (3, 'C'),
    (4, 'D'),
    (5, 'E'),
    (6, 'F')
;


CREATE TABLE friends
    (`id` int, `personId1` int, `personId2` int)
;

INSERT INTO friends
    (`id`, `personId1`, `personId2`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2),
    (2, 3, 1),
    (3, 2, 4),
    (4, 5, 2),
    (5, 3, 4)
;
```

I believe this is set up as you  described: A and B are friends, A and C are friends (notice the inverted relationship), B and D are friends, E and B are friends (another inverted relationship), and C and D are friends.

Assume the id of the person you want is in @personId:

```
SELECT StrangerId, COUNT(MutualFriendId) AS TotalMutualFriends
FROM
(SELECT
  CASE WHEN f.personId2 = mf.friendId THEN f.personId1 ELSE f.personId2 END AS StrangerId,
  CASE WHEN f.personId1 = mf.friendId THEN f.personId1 ELSE f.personId2 END AS MutualFriendId
FROM
(SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN personId1 = @personId THEN personId2 
    ELSE personId1 
  END AS friendId 
FROM friends 
WHERE personId1 = @personId OR personId2 = @personId) AS mf
INNER JOIN friends f
ON (personId1 != @personId AND personId2 = mf.friendId) 
  OR (personId1 = mf.friendId AND personId2 != @personId)
 ) AS totals
 GROUP BY StrangerId
 ORDER BY TotalMutualFriends DESC;
```

Results for @personId = 1 are:

```
StrangerId  TotalMutualFriends
4           2
5           1
```

[And here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47645/27) to demonstrate (I couldn't get it to allow me to set up a variable, so there is a 1 in its place).

Comment: It seems to be half correct answer But where will the *dont fetch me friends* statement i.e `user_id NOT IN($myfriends)` go ?

Comment: `2` is a friend of `1` and `3` is a friend of `1` i said i dont want to show `friends` only `non-friends`

Comment: You did the opposite thing paul You fetched me friends i.e `B` and `C` But i want to get `D`,`E` and `F` in mutual_count. You mutual count in above query was allright though! @paulGriffin

Comment: Ha! The solution is that I reversed my columns in `totals`.  Should be working now.

Comment: @PaulGriffin Very nice answer! Have you considered checking out the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) SE site?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
Select user_id, friends.to_id, count(friend_of_friend.to_id)
from users left outer join
    friends on users.user_id = friends.from_id left outer join
    users as friend_user on friends.to_id = friend_user.user_id left outer  join
    friends as friend_of_friend on friend_user.user_id =    friend_of_friend.from_id and friend_of_friend.to_id in (select to_id from friends where from_id = users.user_id)
Group by USER_ID, friends.to_id
Order by 3
```

Edit for clarity:
The logic of this query depends on joining the same table multiple times. The first two joins are pretty straight-forward, we are starting with a table of users, then joining in the friends table that links each user with all their friends. But then we join in the user table again, but this time using the "to" column - we are getting the user info for each friend. Since we can't have the same table name twice in a query, we give it an alias of "friend_user". Then we join the friends table again, based on the id in the friend_user table - this gives us all the friends of each original user's friends. Then we limit the friends of friends that we get back using the "Friend_of_friend.to_id in ..." to compare the friends of friends to a list of all of the original user's friends, which we bring in by a subquery - the section just after the "in" that is enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Could change the joins to inner joins for efficiency, depending on how you want your results.

Comment: Column 'user_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: If there are other issues, let me know the specifics and I'll try to help and edit.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is `USER_ID` and `3` above in your query @TPhe ?

Comment: User_id should be specified as users.user_id. This is the person that you are starting out with - the person A in your example. The query takes this person's friends, then finds all of their friends that are also friends of the original person. The Order By 3 is a shorthand way of saying "Order by the third column in the select clause". You can also simply re-enter the third column: Order By count(friend_of_friend.to_id)

Comment: Dude it aint fetching what i wanted. Its also giving me persons whom i am already friends with  i.e `B` and `C`. To make things simpler I have already my friends in `$myfriends` variable so by doing `user_id NOT IN($myfriends)` will give the non-friends. Can you edit your answer by using the `$myfriends` in your query ? @TPhe

Comment: @SlimShady: here's a tip. "It ain't working" (and other variations) is not really useful feedback to someone helping you. It is best not to assume that answers provided on Stack Overflow can be used verbatim, since you're the only one that can test them properly. If they don't work first time, consider them like a clue to help you solve it yourself -- or explain to the poster _how_ it doesn't work, so they can offer suggestions on what to try next. HTH!

Comment: I also posted an explanation of my query - I hope that makes it a better answer than just the bare-bones, here's-the-code version. You may need to tweak it for your purposes.